# Find similar items in an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like so:

```
{
    title: "test",
    subtitle: "test",
    "list-item-1": "This is item 1",
    "list-item-2": "This is item 2",
    "list-item-3": "This is item 3"
}
```

I want to find all keys in that object that end with a `-1`, or any `-`numerical value. And then group all of those together in some way that I can access them by calling something like "if an item has a `-1` at the end of it, find all other items that have the same first part (`list-item` in this case) and save them to their own array or variable.

How would I go about this?

Comment: This isn't an array or valid javascript.  Please post valid javascript so we can understand what you're really trying to do here.  Do you  mean for this to be an actual array or properties on an object?  Step 1 to getting an answer is to ask a clear question.

Comment: Good God I didn't know it was a crime to post something "not valid". Sorry for my misunderstanding. I guess that's why I posted this in the first place: to seek help...

Comment: If you're asking how to do something to a data structure, you need to post a valid data structure otherwise we can't tell what you're asking.  In this case, we couldn't tell what you're really trying to do.  Your title said array, but your code looks sorts of like an object (though it was missing commas so it wasn't even a valid object).  OK, now that you've fixed the code to be a valid object (I had to remove one trailing comma), I've edited your title to no longer mention an array since there is no array involved.

Comment: Okay, well thank you for the edit. As I'm learning JS, the "terms" is something I struggle with.

Answer (score 2):

one simple way to harvest properties is to use built in methods like keys(), filter(), and test():

```
var obj={
    title: "test",
    subtitle: "test",
    "list-item-1": "This is item 1",
    "list-item-2": "This is item 2",
    "list-item-3": "This is item 3",
};

var arrOK=Object.keys(obj).filter(/./.test, /list-item-\d+$/);
alert(arrOK); // shows: "list-item-1,list-item-2,list-item-3"
```

Comment: Thanks! However, there could be other properties that need to be grouped besides just `"list-item-#"`. So specifically saying `/list-item-\d+$/` won't exactly work. But I'll play around with this and see  if I can't get it working.

Comment: that's cool, you would need only alter the RegExp to handle that change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it isn't an array - that is a Javascript Object, however it is malformed in that there are not commas between items.

You can iterate through the object like so, and access the name of each object property as below.

```
for (item in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    // the 'item' variable is the name you are looking for.
    // use a regex pattern to match on -#.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..in` to iterate over the object keys and then just do some simple string/regex matching.

```
var new_obj = {};
// iterate over keys in object
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // ends in "dash number"
        if (key.match(/-\d+$/)) {
            // get new key by stripping off "dash number"
            var newkey = key.replace(/-\d+$/, "");
            // ensure new object has this property; make it an array
            if (!new_obj.hasOwnProperty(newkey)) {
                new_obj[newkey] = [];
            }
            // append original object item to this new property
            new_obj.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```